# DevDemon Channel Videos is now returning https://youtube.com/devicesupport

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

Apparently YouTube has changed their API which seems to have killed Channel Videos. When searching for a video in the add-on, the devicesupport video comes up. I'm really hoping that there's a fix for this!

This post https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?p=yt_devicesupport&hl=en&rd=1 indicates that the change to the API was made at the beginning of May.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have released a new version of Channel Videos:

http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/channel-videos

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please [edit](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/posts/31357/edit) your previous answer and update the info, instead of having an obsolete answer? After that, you can delete this answer to make it looks cleaner. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick turn around time on this! Saved my butt!

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of the issue and are working on updating the API. We will be releasing an update to the product.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but things map pretty well to the new api. Here is the youtubeSearchVideos js function updated and working. I started working on this and thought I should share.

```
function youtubeSearchVideos(params, customField) {
    var i, entry, video_id;
    if (params.author) params.keywords += " " + params.author;
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/",
        data: {
            part: "snippet",
            type: "videos",
            q: params.keywords,
            key: "AIzaSyBpu8hgnXbkqFVWrAvwRUEz7T13ii3I7WM",
            maxResults: params.limit
        },
        success: function(rdata) {
            var Videos = [];
           /* if (typeof rdata.feed === "undefined") {
                addVideoResults("youtube", Videos, customField);
            }
            if (typeof rdata.feed.entry === "undefined") {
                addVideoResults("youtube", Videos, customField);
            }*/
            for (var i = 0; i < rdata.items.length; i++) {
                entry = rdata.items[i];
                video_id = entry.id.videoId;
                Videos.push({
                    id: video_id,
                    title: entry.snippet.title,
                    img_url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + video_id + "/default.jpg",
                    vid_url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id
                });
            }
            addVideoResults("youtube", Videos, customField);
        }
    });
}
```

Best,
Cory